# MySQL Upgrade 5.7 to 8.0 Failing to Start Service

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

I am trying to upgrade MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 .
The process me following is I am taking Backup of Data Directory of MySQL 5.7 and then using same Data Directory of MySQL 5.7 for Upgrading to 8.0 , while Doing this at end MySQL service is Failing to Start.

Please Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what errors are showing in the error log(s)?  what operating system is this?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2.  

Main issue after upgarding I am not able to Start MySQL Service and getting Below error :-
                                      
The MYSQL8 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs. I am not able to START MySQL Service.

Thanks.